# AWS Athena: Named boto3 queries not creating corresponding tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-athena

I have the following `boto3` draft script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import boto3

client = boto3.client('athena')

BUCKETS='buckets.txt'
DATABASE='some_db'
QUERY_STR="""CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_db.{}(
         BucketOwner STRING,
         Bucket STRING,
         RequestDateTime STRING,
         RemoteIP STRING,
         Requester STRING,
         RequestID STRING,
         Operation STRING,
         Key STRING,
         RequestURI_operation STRING,
         RequestURI_key STRING,
         RequestURI_httpProtoversion STRING,
         HTTPstatus STRING,
         ErrorCode STRING,
         BytesSent BIGINT,
         ObjectSize BIGINT,
         TotalTime STRING,
         TurnAroundTime STRING,
         Referrer STRING,
         UserAgent STRING,
         VersionId STRING,
         HostId STRING,
         SigV STRING,
         CipherSuite STRING,
         AuthType STRING,
         EndPoint STRING,
         TLSVersion STRING
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
         'serialization.format' = '1', 'input.regex' = '([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) \\[(.*?)\\] ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) \\\"([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (- |[^ ]*)\\\" (-|[0-9]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (\"[^\"]*\") ([^ ]*)(?: ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*))?.*$' )
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/{}'"""

with open(BUCKETS, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()


for line in lines:
    query_string = QUERY_STR.format(line, line)
    response = client.create_named_query(
        Name=line,
        Database=DATABASE,
        QueryString=QUERY_STR
    )
    print(response)
```

When executed, all responses come back with status code `200`.

Why am I not able to see the corresponding tables that should have been created?

Shouldn't I be able to (at least) see somewhere those queries stored?

**update1**: I am now trying to actually create the tables via the above queries as follows:

```py
for line in lines:
    query_string = QUERY_STR.format(DATABASE, line[:-1].replace('-', '_'), line[:-1])
    try:
        response1 = client.start_query_execution(
            QueryString=query_string,
            WorkGroup=WORKGROUP,
            QueryExecutionContext={
                'Database': DATABASE
            },
            ResultConfiguration={
                'OutputLocation': OUTPUT_BUCKET,
            },
        )
        query_execution_id = response1['ResponseMetadata']['RequestId']
        print(query_execution_id)
    except Exception as e1:
        print(query_string)
        raise(e1)
```

Once again, the script does output some query ids (no error seems to take place), nonetheless no table is created.

I have also followed the advice of @John Rotenstein and initialised my `boto3` client as follows:

```
client = boto3.client('athena', region_name='us-east-1')
```

Comment: It is possible that you are sending the boto3 command to a different region. Try it with: `client = boto3.client('athena', region_name='us-west-2')` (or whatever region you are using).

Comment: thanks but this did not work either; also check my update on the question.

Comment: Can you see a query that you submitted with `start_query_execution()` under the history tab in Athena console in us-east-1 region? Also, your unformatted  `QUERY_STR` contains `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_db.{}`. Do you have **some_db** defined in AWS Glue catalog?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `response` simply tells you that your request has been successfully submitted. Method `create_named_query()` creates a snippet of your query, which then can be seen/access in AWS Athena console in **Saved Queries** tab.

[image]

It seems to me that you want to create table using `boto3`. If that is the case, you need to use [`start_query_execution()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution) method.

> Runs the SQL query statements contained in the Query . Requires you to have access to the workgroup in which the query ran.

Having response 200 out of `start_query_execution` doesn't guarantee that you query will get executed successfully. As I understand, this method does some simple pre-execution checks to validate syntax of the query. However, there are other things that could fail you query at the run time. For example if you try to create table in a database that doesn't exist, or if you try to create a table definition in a database to which you don't have access.

Here is an example, when I used you query string, formatted with with some random name for the table.

[image]

I got response 200 and got some value in `response1['ResponseMetadata']['RequestId']`. However, since I don't have `some_db` in AWS Glue catalog, this query failed at the run time, thus, no table was created.

Here is how you can track query execution within boto3

```py
import time

response1 = client.start_query_execution(
    QueryString=query_string,
    WorkGroup=WORKGROUP,
    QueryExecutionContext={
        'Database': DATABASE
    },
    ResultConfiguration={
        'OutputLocation': OUTPUT_BUCKET,
    },
)
query_execution_id = response1['ResponseMetadata']['RequestId']

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    response_2 = client.get_query_execution(
        QueryExecutionId=query_execution_id
    )
    query_status = response_2['QueryExecution']['Status']
    print(query_status)
    if query_status not in ["QUEUED", "RUNNING", "CANCELLED"]:
        break
```

Comment: I am not able to see any queries under 'Saved Queries' either...I really wonder how is this possible...

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- In the Athena console, I ran:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE foo
```

- In the Athena console, I selected `foo` in the Database drop-down
- To start things simple, I ran this Python code:

```py
import boto3

athena_client = boto3.client('athena', region_name='ap-southeast-2') # Change as necessary

QUERY_STR="""
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo.bar(id INT) 
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/input-files/'
"""

response = athena_client.start_query_execution(
    QueryString=QUERY_STR,
    QueryExecutionContext={'Database': 'foo'},
    ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': 's3://my-bucket/athena-out/'}
)
```

- I then went to the Athena console, did a refresh, and confirmed that the `bar` table was created

**Suggestion:** Try the above to confirm that it works for you, too!

I then ran your code, using the `start_query_execution` version of your code (shown in your second code block). I had to make some changes:

- I didn't have a `buckets.txt` file, so I just provided a list of names
- Your code doesn't show the content of `OUTPUT_BUCKET`, so I used `s3://my-bucket/athena-output/` (Does that match the format that *you* used?)
- Your code uses `QUERY_STR.format(DATABASE...` but there was no `{}` in the `QUERY_STR` where the database name would be inserted, so I removed `DATABASE` as an input to the format variable
- I did *not* provide a value for `WORKGROUP`

**It all ran fine**, creating multiple tables.

So, check the above bullet-points to see if it caused a problem for you (such as replacing the Database name in the `format()` statement).

Comment: Thanks for getting through all this trouble!  will run what you suggested and post the results.