# AWS Athena + boto3: How am I supposed to execute named queries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

Concerning the following draft script I would like to know: How can I execute the named query I created?
I can access the query via the browser interface, but would like to execute it via the Session.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58736295/aws-athena-named-boto3-queries-not-creating-corresponding-tables) the answer is to use the `client.start_query_execution(...)` command. But whats the point when it is not the named query I created but instead a non-named query with the same query_string. Or am I missing something essential in how to use this?

```py
import boto3

sess = boto3.session.Session(
    region_name=region,
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY
)
 
athenaclient = sess.client('athena')

query_string = '''
SELECT *
FROM "ccindex"."ccindex"
WHERE crawl = 'CC-MAIN-2020-34'
  AND subset = 'warc'
  AND url_host_tld = 'de'
  AND url_query IS NULL
  AND url_path like '%impressum%'
LIMIT 20000
'''

resp = athenaclient.create_named_query(
    Name='filter-ccindex-de',
    Description='Filter *.de/impressum websites of Common Crawl index',
    Database='ccindex',
    QueryString=query_string
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a direct option to pass named query to your `start_query_execution` method.But this can be achieved by using [`get_named_query`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.get_named_query) which accepts `Name` of the named query and returns `QueryString` in response.

Then you can parse this response and pass `QueryString` to `start_query_execution` method.

Comment: Thank you! I might have to do it this way then.
I would like to use named_query to either add one and run it. Or if it has already been run, skip this part and go straight to retrieve results. This would be easy with log of named queries.

How would you check for duplicate runs? Would you compare the query parameters to the history?

Comment: you can then use get_query_execution to get query and compare it to see if it already ran. But how are you running this query? Why there will be duplicate runs?